# How can I determine variable scope in this C# Webforms example?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I pass that values of the two variables to the `ShowFooBar` click event?

When I run the code below, the variables have no values in the write statement.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string foo = String.Empty;
    string bar = String.Empty;

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeCondition(x,y))
        {
            foo = "apple";
            bar = "orange";
        }
    }

    protected void ShowFooBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("foo=" + foo + "& bar=" + bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use if(IsPostback) { } on the page_load event i think to maintain the values of the variables.

Comment: I solved this problem by writing the values to page Literals and them retrieving them on the in the second Click event.

Comment: Why use page literals when ViewState is built in?

Comment: Andy Rose, interesting comment, is there a distinction between the two approaches?

Comment: @mmcglynn - no real distinction, just a little less work as you do not need to add anything to the form to store your variables. ViewState has its critics, and rightly so, but in this case I would think it would be the ideal tool for the job in hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web forms are stateless which means each time you postback to one of these click events then a new page object will be created from the _Default class where foo and bar are instantiated as empty strings, hence the ShowFooBar_Click event will display just that.
If you wish to persist the values of foo and bar between requests you are going to have to store them somewhere and retrieve them during the event request. Various options are available depending on your need such as Session, ViewState, hidden fields etc. For example:

```
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeCondition(x,y))
        {
            ViewState["foo"] = "apple";
            ViewState["bar"] = "orange";
        }
    }

    protected void ShowFooBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ViewState["foo"] != null && ViewState["bar"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write("foo=" + ViewState["foo"] + "& bar=" + ViewState["bar"]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they wouldn't. On each postback, the class is re-instantiated, so the values will have gone. You could either persist them to a cookie or database, or add them as form fields.

Comment: The problem with retrieving the values from a database is how would I determine the value to select? It's the same problem.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Pankaj Garg, see my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeCondition(x, y))
        {
            ViewState["foo"] = "apple";
            ViewState["bar"] = "orange";
        }
    }

    protected void ShowFooBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("foo=" + ViewState["foo"].ToString() + "& bar=" + ViewState["bar"].ToString());
    }
}
```